# How to replace contents of <tr> tags using Ajax?

Tags: html, ajax, jsp

I'm working with jsp and ajax.
I'm trying to replace the innerHTML of the `<tr>` tag using ajax, which is not working for me-

```
<tr id="replace">
</tr>
```

The page which I call using ajax-

```
<td>
<% 
String id = request.getParameter("id");
out.println("<h3>"+id+"</h3>");
%>
</td>
```

But the following works, which I dont require-

```
<tr>
<td id="replace"></td>
</tr>
```

page called-

```
<% 
String id = request.getParameter("id");
out.println("<h3>"+id+"</h3>");
%>
```

So in short, what do I need to do to replace the innerHTML of an entire `<tr>` tag and not just one `<td>` tag ?

Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IE at least, and I don't know why, innerHTML is read-only for `<tr>`. Those are the little annoyances that made jQuery so popular: it circumvents those bizarre and inconsistent behaviors and provide a more logical and functional API. I would simply use JQuery:

```
$('#replace').html(theNewHtml);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/fxUwS/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your control is inverted.  Your server side code should return the results, and your client-side should decide how to render it.  That is, get your id and write to your inner HTML based on the results of the Ajax; don't try to have your server do this.